# How to make login.php and validate with mysql database table

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation

How to do login.php that validates with mysql database table two columns. I mean I have table users under database suite. There is two columns: user and pwd.

I have to make basic HTML or PHP page that client introduces user and pwd, if password or pwd is correct it will redirect to report.php.

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html is a start if you didnt do jack yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you got anything together for us to work from?

Comment: i have basic PHP knowledge, when i say basic its very basic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just try this:

```
##session and include session stored variable
session_start();

##get connection
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

    ##check database
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link) or die(DB_ERROR_LOGS);

    ##do operation
    if($_REQUEST["op"]=="login"){
        sleep(1); 
        ##encrypt password by md5
        $md5_pwd = md5($_POST["Password"]);
        $tmp_account = $_POST["Username"];
        $caselower_account = strtolower($tmp_account);
        $account_approve = "false";
        $sql_login_account = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ='".$caselower_account."';";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_login_account) or die("Invalid Username");
        while($login_account = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if($login_account['password'] == $md5_pwd){
                $account_approve = "true";
                $_SESSION['login'] = "true";
                $_SESSION['user'] = $caselower_account;
                setcookie("cookiename","cookiename",time() + 3600,'/');
                echo "success";
            }else{
                $account_approve = "false";
            }
        }
        ##if true, redirect to report.php
        if($account_approve=="true"){
            header("Location:report.php"); 
        }
        ##if false, redirect to login.php to re-enter your username and password
        else{
            $_SESSION['login'] = "false";
            setcookie("cookiename","",time() - 3600,'/');
            header("Location:login.php");  
        }
    }elseif($_REQUEST["op"]=="logout") {
        $_SESSION['login'] = "false";
        setcookie("cookiename","",time() - 3600,'/');
        header("Location:login.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['login'] = "false";
        setcookie("cookiename","",time() - 3600,'/');
        header("Location:login.php");
    }
```

I used session to pass inputbox's username and password to this page.
Instead, you can use post to pass your username and password to this page.